# MinGW error Compiling into something usable

Tags: mingw

I'm having an issue with getting a simple C++ script to compile.

```
#include <iostream>
using namespace std;

// A C++ Program to output a greeting.

int Main(){
    cout << "Hello World!" << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

and whenever I run g++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe, or c++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe, I get the below error message,

```
c:\MinGW\bin>g++ hello.cpp -o hello.exe
c:/mingw/bin/../lib/gcc/mingw32/6.3.0/../../../libmingw32.a(main.o):
(.text.startup+0xa0): undefined reference to `WinMain@16'
collect2.exe: error: ld returned 1 exit status
```

Fairly new to C and C++ so any direction will be greatly appreciated.  I'm not even sure what is being referenced here as the error.

Answer (score 1):

Ok, perhaps this is going to be more daunting than I anticipated...

My original code from above might have a had a few spacial errors.  I did not have a blank first line or a blank last line.  I added those and I received the same error.  I changed

```
int Main(){...}
```

to

```
int main(){...}
```

and there you have it... a simple hello world program I can run from cmd...

oh boy.